# Get height vector

Tags: vectors

I have tree points:

$$A=\pmatrix{1\\-2\\-3}  B= \pmatrix{-2\\3\\2}  C= \pmatrix{0\\2\\4}$$

Now i have to get the height vector that ends on $AC$.
The solution should be:

$$f:x = \pmatrix{-2\\3\\2} + r * \pmatrix{-2.1212...\\1.4848..\\-1.1515...} $$

I understand why the vector starts at $B$ but I don't know how to get the direction vector!

**Sorry about the .1212.. .4848.., i think you understand what i mean but i didn't know how to format it! I would be glad if somebody can correct my question! Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to perform [vector rejection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection#Vector_rejection_2):
\begin{align*}
\vec v &= \vec{AB} - \frac{\vec{AB} \cdot \vec{AC}}{\vec{AC} \cdot \vec{AC}}\vec{AC} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} -3 \\ 5 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix} - \frac{\begin{pmatrix} -3 \\ 5 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 4 \\ 7 \end{pmatrix}}{\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 4 \\ 7 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 4 \\ 7 \end{pmatrix}}\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 4 \\ 7 \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} -3 \\ 5 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix} - \frac{29}{33}\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 4 \\ 7 \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} -70/33 \\ 49/33 \\ -38/33 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks is there another way?